# How does RXD/TXD request signal look betwen 16u2 and 328p on oscilloscope?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328, bootloader

I have a broken Arduino Uno. The man tells that he connected power supply and USB at the same time.

I got the new 16u2 (empty) chip. then asked my friend to re-solder it. He was using an air soldering station, but that did not work out. Then I try do that by myself. After 6 or 8 time I was successful. I think.

With stk500v2 programmer thru ICSP I burned in the hardware called:

```
Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex
```

which I found in Arduino "hardware" folder.

I then burned bootloader to 328p controller:

```
optiboot_atmega328.hex
```

That hardware also from Arduino folder.

The problem is that I can upload sketch

```
error: avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

meaning that device not recognizing.

My PC founds Arduino in device manager. 328p with ICSP programmable and working. (checked with blinking.hex 13 pin)

When pressing reset button the 13 led turns of then blinks fast several times that means the boot loader installed property.

Right after pressing upload the Rx blinks 3 times after that I am getting error.

Strange isn't it?

So what I what to know:

- I suppose the first must start blinking Tx led?
- Can anyone show me how must look like rxd txd interrupts?
- So about my assumption that I overheated 16u2 and it does strange things. What are you thinking about that?

Comment: You used both ICSP connectors, right?

Comment: yes. one to 16u2 near 16u2 another to 328p near 328p

Comment: Have you plugged an oscilloscope on RX and TX already? Could you post a picture of what you observed?

Comment: I cant put picture. but I can describe... I see 3 negative packets about to 1.7 V in 5ms. weight of packet about 3mm and its RxD scope.. on TxD I see only all line pushed  down about 0.3V for a moments... but I feel that its not that what I want. can anyone answer my question before? which first impulse I must see RxD or TxD because the impulse what I described is RxD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See screenshot below. The Rx on the Uno (incoming data) should flash first.

[image: Uno boot sequence]

The programmer sends `STK_GET_SYNC` and the board replies `STK_INSYNC`:

```
Sent: STK_GET_SYNC / CRC_EOP  (30/20)
Got: STK_INSYNC / STK_OK (14/10)
```

Afterwards you see the bigger blocks on the lower line as the programmer sends the hex code to the board. Then about half-way through the bigger blocks are on the top as the board sends back the verification data (by reading the flash back).

The little blips would be the other side acknowledging a packet of data.

---

For more details see [What happens when code is uploaded using the bootloader?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15936/what-happens-when-code-is-uploaded-using-the-bootloader)