# Why does the PIN 13 LED of Uno R3 blink every time I upload some code?

Tags: arduino-uno, digital

I was driving a relay from Arduino Uno R3 Pin 13. I observed that every time I upload some code the led on the board designating pin 13 would blink. I'm curious why this is so. I understand that the serial LED blinks cause there's a serial transmission but why an IO pin?

Answer (score 4):

See [What happens when code is uploaded using the bootloader?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15936/what-happens-when-code-is-uploaded-using-the-bootloader) - the flashing is by design.

[image: Optiboot flashing pin 13]

Probably the reason is to confirm that the bootloader has started.

Answer (score 1):

It's driven by the bootloader, which is performing the flashing (I suppose you are flashing through the USB port).

Answer (score -1):

To show that the bootloader is functioning satisfactorily to the hobbyist. Boot loader helps to upload new sketch on the chip.