# Arduino IDE stopped uploading sketches to BLEduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, bootloader

I know similar questions to this have been asked before, but I have a "resp=0x**10**" which I haven't found elsewhere, so maybe it's different, the board is also not an Arduino Uno although it's should be fully compatible with it in adition to the Bluetooth part.

I'm a beginner to Arduino (and electronics in general) and I bought a [Bleduino board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board). It was working without problems, I've tested a servo and a DC motor (with a motors shield) without problems. But, it suddenly stopped working! I basically can't upload any sketch no matter what I try, giving me this error (10 attempts):

```
         Using Port                    : COM11
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x10

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I did try the reset button before uploading (actually tried both black and white reset buttons on this board), double checked I'm using the correct board and ports.

I've used an old 12V power supply with 1000mA, so maybe that damaged the main chip? The L and LINK LEDs light up though when connected to usb or jack, and the bluetooth also connects to the IOS App.

I read [this][3] thorough answer for similar problems and my board passes the loopback test, but while uploading, only the L and RX LEDs flash!

Have I damaged the main chip? Do I have to buy a AVR programmer and burn a new Bootloader?

**Edit:**

A screenshot of wiring to test the Atmega16U2chip:

[image]

ATmega328Pchip Response:

```
Atmega chip detector.        
Written by Nick Gammon.        
Version 1.18        
Compiled on Apr 10 2016 at 10:30:58 with Arduino IDE 10607.        
Attempting to enter ICSP programming mode ...        
Entered programming mode OK.        
Signature = 0x1E 0x95 0x0F         
Processor = ATmega328P        
Flash memory size = 32768 bytes.        
LFuse = 0xFF         
HFuse = 0xDE         
EFuse = 0xFF         
Lock byte = 0xFF         
Clock calibration = 0x96         
Bootloader in use: Yes        
EEPROM preserved through erase: No        
Watchdog timer always on: No        
Bootloader is 512 bytes starting at 7E00        

Bootloader:        

7E00: 0x11 0x24 0x84 0xB7 0x14 0xBE 0x81 0xFF 0xF0 0xD0 0x85 0xE0 0x80 0x93 0x81 0x00         
7E10: 0x82 0xE0 0x80 0x93 0xC0 0x00 0x88 0xE1 0x80 0x93 0xC1 0x00 0x86 0xE0 0x80 0x93         
7E20: 0xC2 0x00 0x80 0xE1 0x80 0x93 0xC4 0x00 0x8E 0xE0 0xC9 0xD0 0x25 0x9A 0x86 0xE0         
7E30: 0x20 0xE3 0x3C 0xEF 0x91 0xE0 0x30 0x93 0x85 0x00 0x20 0x93 0x84 0x00 0x96 0xBB         
7E40: 0xB0 0x9B 0xFE 0xCF 0x1D 0x9A 0xA8 0x95 0x81 0x50 0xA9 0xF7 0xCC 0x24 0xDD 0x24         
7E50: 0x88 0x24 0x83 0x94 0xB5 0xE0 0xAB 0x2E 0xA1 0xE1 0x9A 0x2E 0xF3 0xE0 0xBF 0x2E         
7E60: 0xA2 0xD0 0x81 0x34 0x61 0xF4 0x9F 0xD0 0x08 0x2F 0xAF 0xD0 0x02 0x38 0x11 0xF0         
7E70: 0x01 0x38 0x11 0xF4 0x84 0xE0 0x01 0xC0 0x83 0xE0 0x8D 0xD0 0x89 0xC0 0x82 0x34         
7E80: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7E90: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7EA0: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7EB0: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7EC0: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7ED0: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7EE0: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7EF0: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF         
7F00: 0xA6 0x01 0xA0 0xE0 0xB1 0xE0 0x2C 0x91 0x30 0xE0 0x11 0x96 0x8C 0x91 0x11 0x97         
7F10: 0x90 0xE0 0x98 0x2F 0x88 0x27 0x82 0x2B 0x93 0x2B 0x12 0x96 0xFA 0x01 0x0C 0x01         
7F20: 0x87 0xBE 0xE8 0x95 0x11 0x24 0x4E 0x5F 0x5F 0x4F 0xF1 0xE0 0xA0 0x38 0xBF 0x07         
7F30: 0x51 0xF7 0xF6 0x01 0xA7 0xBE 0xE8 0x95 0x07 0xB6 0x00 0xFC 0xFD 0xCF 0x97 0xBE         
7F40: 0xE8 0x95 0x26 0xC0 0x84 0x37 0xB1 0xF4 0x2E 0xD0 0x2D 0xD0 0xF8 0x2E 0x2B 0xD0         
7F50: 0x3C 0xD0 0xF6 0x01 0xEF 0x2C 0x8F 0x01 0x0F 0x5F 0x1F 0x4F 0x84 0x91 0x1B 0xD0         
7F60: 0xEA 0x94 0xF8 0x01 0xC1 0xF7 0x08 0x94 0xC1 0x1C 0xD1 0x1C 0xFA 0x94 0xCF 0x0C         
7F70: 0xD1 0x1C 0x0E 0xC0 0x85 0x37 0x39 0xF4 0x28 0xD0 0x8E 0xE1 0x0C 0xD0 0x85 0xE9         
7F80: 0x0A 0xD0 0x8F 0xE0 0x7A 0xCF 0x81 0x35 0x11 0xF4 0x88 0xE0 0x18 0xD0 0x1D 0xD0         
7F90: 0x80 0xE1 0x01 0xD0 0x65 0xCF 0x98 0x2F 0x80 0x91 0xC0 0x00 0x85 0xFF 0xFC 0xCF         
7FA0: 0x90 0x93 0xC6 0x00 0x08 0x95 0x80 0x91 0xC0 0x00 0x87 0xFF 0xFC 0xCF 0x80 0x91         
7FB0: 0xC0 0x00 0x84 0xFD 0x01 0xC0 0xA8 0x95 0x80 0x91 0xC6 0x00 0x08 0x95 0xE0 0xE6         
7FC0: 0xF0 0xE0 0x98 0xE1 0x90 0x83 0x80 0x83 0x08 0x95 0xED 0xDF 0x80 0x32 0x19 0xF0         
7FD0: 0x88 0xE0 0xF5 0xDF 0xFF 0xCF 0x84 0xE1 0xDE 0xCF 0x1F 0x93 0x18 0x2F 0xE3 0xDF         
7FE0: 0x11 0x50 0xE9 0xF7 0xF2 0xDF 0x1F 0x91 0x08 0x95 0x80 0xE0 0xE8 0xDF 0xEE 0x27         
7FF0: 0xFF 0x27 0x09 0x94 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x04 0x04         

MD5 sum of bootloader = 0xEA 0x3C 0x5C 0xA9 0x35 0xD1 0x36 0xA6 0x71 0xD1 0xB2 0x3F 0x7E 0x62 0x79 0x6F         
Bootloader MD5 sum not known.        

First 256 bytes of program memory:        

0: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
10: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
20: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
30: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
40: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
50: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
60: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
70: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00         
80: 0x10 0x20 0x40 0x80 0x01 0x02 0x04 0x08 0x10 0x20 0x01 0x02 0x04 0x08 0x10 0x20         
90: 0x04 0x04 0x04 0x04 0x04 0x04 0x04 0x04 0x02 0x02 0x02 0x02 0x02 0x02 0x03 0x03         
A0: 0x03 0x03 0x03 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x25 0x00 0x28 0x00 0x2B 0x00 0x00 0x00         
B0: 0x00 0x00 0x24 0x00 0x27 0x00 0x2A 0x00 0x2A 0x01 0x7D 0x02 0x11 0x24 0x1F 0xBE         
C0: 0xCF 0xEF 0xD8 0xE0 0xDE 0xBF 0xCD 0xBF 0x11 0xE0 0xA0 0xE0 0xB1 0xE0 0xE2 0xE0         
D0: 0xF8 0xE0 0x02 0xC0 0x05 0x90 0x0D 0x92 0xA8 0x30 0xB1 0x07 0xD9 0xF7 0x21 0xE0         
E0: 0xA8 0xE0 0xB1 0xE0 0x01 0xC0 0x1D 0x92 0xA7 0x31 0xB2 0x07 0xE1 0xF7 0x10 0xE0         
F0: 0xCC 0xEB 0xD0 0xE0 0x04 0xC0 0x22 0x97 0xFE 0x01 0x0E 0x94 0xFB 0x03 0xC8 0x3B         

Programming mode off.
```

Comment: Thank you Nick! I think I'll have to wait then till I buy an Arduino board and test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this post about the uploading process](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15936/what-happens-when-code-is-uploaded-using-the-bootloader) a response of 0x10 is **STK_OK**. Now while that looks fine, if the uploader is expecting **STK_INSYNC** then it's not OK.

I suggest you go through more of the steps in the [link you posted](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board).

You could use the "board detector" sketch mentioned on that page, to see if the main chip is completely gone, or if there is another issue. Other issues might be things plugged into D0 and D1, wrong baud rate, wrong clock rate, etc.

Comment: Hi again!,

I've an Arduino Uno and tested with and apparently I have a failed ATmega16U2 chip!

Comment: It seems odd to me that a failed chip makes *any* sort of response. You reported it responded STK_OK each time.

Comment: I followed your instructions about that chip testing and I got: 

`
Atmega chip detector.
Written by Nick Gammon.
Version 1.18
Compiled on Apr  9 2016 at 23:55:08 with Arduino IDE 10607.
Attempting to enter ICSP programming mode ......................................................
Failed to enter programming mode. Double-check wiring!
Programming mode off.
`

And here's a screenshot of the wiring:
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1g1FwSVdRbXvbCnni7B2IcTjKRKjEgKMbbYRF2AxtWfs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: And here's what I got when testing the ATmega328P chip:

[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13GBhszDpCCtJHX1Y7MRn4AzCIbAqnvQoq68Y52EbCtU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Google Drive: You need permission` - how about editing your question and including relevant extra details in that, rather than an off-site link?

Comment: Yes sure I'll do that in few hours

Comment: I've edited the post. Please review.

Comment: `A screenshot of wiring to test the Atmega16U2chip: Processor = ATmega328P` - it's not a Atmega16U2chip is it?

Comment: I really don't know what's the difference, I'm new to this, but I wired to the pins beside the usb socket as you advised.

Comment: According to this page, it's the BLE firmware Burn http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=BLEDUINO

Comment: The schematic is a bit hard to read, but it doesn't look like it has a Atmega16U2 chip on it. `it suddenly stopped working` - sounds like you damaged something, but that chip looks OK, except that it has an unknown bootloader (not necessarily a bad thing).

Comment: So, what do you advise me to do? Would using an AVR programmer solve the problem?

Comment: Read the [link](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board) about problems uploading. You may possibly be able to program the chip with an AVR programmer. I can't say for sure.

Comment: Nick, I'm sorry but I must say THANK YOU! I've been able to solve the problem using the "ATmega328P responds but has no bootloader" part of your fantastic post! I'm able to upload to BLEduino board once again :)