# Monitor serial0 while code is being uploaded

Tags: serial, uploading, uart, avrdude, programmer

I'm trying to upload the sketch on a Mega 2560 via the serial port 0 using another microcontroller.

To better undestand the process, I decided to first observe what avrdude is doing while it is uploading a hex file. To do this, I'm using another arduino (ESP32) with the following sketch:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial2.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
    while (Serial2.available()) {
        Serial.print(Serial2.read(), HEX);
        Serial.print(":");
    }
}
```

ESP32's `Serial`(`serial0`) is connected to PC via USB, and Serial2 is connected to Mega's `Serial`(`serial0`), the one connected to PC via USB, used by avrdude.
[image]
According to [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/15937/59845) answer the first things avrdude is sending over the serial interface are:

```
STK_GET_SYNC / CRC_EOP  (0x30/0x20)
```

But this is not what I receive through ESP32:

```
1B:1:0:1:E:1:14:1B:2:0:C:E:10:C8:64:19:20:0:53:3:AC:53:0:0:31:1B:3:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:30:0:0:0:33:1B:4:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:30:0:1:0:35:1B:5:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:30:0:2:0:37:1B:6:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:0:0:0:56:1B:7:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:0:0:0:57:1B:8:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:0:0:0:58:1B:9:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:58:8:0:0:59:1B:A:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:58:8:0:0:5A:1B:B:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:58:8:0:0:5B:1B:C:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:8:0:0:54:1B:D:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:8:0:0:55:1B:E:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:8:0:0:56:1B:F:0:5:E:6:80:0:0:0:99:1B:10:1:A:E:13:1:0:C1:A:40:4C:20:0:0:71:C0:0:0:81:C0:0:0:7F:C0:0:0:7D:C0:0:0:7B:C0:0:0:79:C0:0:0:77:C0:0:0:75:C0:0:0:73:C0:0:0:71:C0:0:0:6F:C0:0:0:6D:C0:0:0:6B:C0:0:0:69:C0:0:0:67:C0:0:0:65:C0:0:0:63:C0:0:0:61:C0:0:0:5F:C0:0:0:5D:C0:0:0:5B:C0:0:0:59:C0:0:0:57:C0:0:0:56:C0:0:0:53:C0:0:0:51:C0:0:0:4F:C0:0:0:4D:C0:0:0:4B:C0:0:0:49:C0:0:0:47:C0:0:0:45:C0:0:0:43:C0:0:0:41:C0:0:0:3F:C0:0:0:3D:C0:0:0:3B:C0:0:0:39:C0:0:0:37:C0:0:0:35:C0:0:0:33:C0:0:0:31:C0:0:0:2F:C0:0:0:2D:C0:0:0:2B:C0:0:0:29:C0:0:0:27:C0:0:0:25:C0:0:0:23:C0:0:0:21:C0:0:0:1F:C0:0:0:1D:C0:0:0:1B:C0:0:0:19:C0:0:0:17:C0:0:0:15:C0:0:0:13:C0:0:0:11:24:1F:BE:CF:EF:D1:E2:DE:BF:CD:BF:0:E0:C:BF:22:E0:A0:E0:B2:E0:1:C0:1D:92:A9:30:19:1B:11:0:5:E:6:80:0:0:80:7:1B:12:1:A:E:13:1:0:C1:A:40:4C:20:0:0:B2:7:E1:F7:4C:D0:C2:C0:7B:CF:1F:92:F:92:F:B6:F:92:11:24:2F:93:3F:93:8F:93:9F:93:AF:93:BF:93:80:91:5:2:90:91:6:2:A0:91:7:2:B0:91:8:2:30:91:4:2:23:E0:23:F:2D:37:20:F4:1:96:A1:1D:B1:1D:5:C0:26:E8:23:F:2:96:A1:1D:B1:1D:20:93:4:2:80:93:5:2:90:93:6:2:A0:93:7:2:B0:93:8:2:80:91:0:2:90:91:1:2:A0:91:2:2:B0:91:3:2:1:96:A1:1D:B1:1D:80:93:0:2:90:93:1:2:A0:93:2:2:B0:93:3:2:BF:91:AF:91:9F:91:8F:91:3F:91:2F:91:F:90:F:BE:F:90:1F:90:18:95:78:94:84:B5:82:60:84:BD:84:B5:81:60:84:BD:85:B5:82:60:85:BD:85:B5:81:60:85:BD:80:91:6E:0:81:60:80:93:6E:0:10:92:81:0:80:91:81:0:82:60:80:93:81:0:80:91:81:0:81:60:80:93:81:0:80:91:80:0:81:60:80:93:80:0:80:91:B1:0:84:60:80:93:B1:0:80:91:B0:0:81:60:1B:13:0:5:E:6:80:0:1:0:84:1B:14:1:A:E:13:1:0:C1:A:40:4C:20:0:0:91:0:80:91:91:0:81:60:80:93:91:0:80:91:90:0:81:60:80:93:90:0:80:91:A1:0:82:60:80:93:A1:0:80:91:A1:0:81:60:80:93:A1:0:80:91:A0:0:81:60:80:93:A0:0:80:91:21:1:82:60:80:93:21:1:80:91:21:1:81:60:80:93:21:1:80:91:20:1:81:7A:0:80:91:7A:0:81:60:80:93:7A:0:80:91:7A:0:80:68:80:93:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:1B:15:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:0:0:0:45:1B:16:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:0:0:0:46:1B:17:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:0:0:0:47:1B:18:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:58:8:0:0:48:1B:19:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:58:8:0:0:49:1B:1A:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:58:8:0:0:4A:1B:1B:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:8:0:0:43:1B:1C:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:8:0:0:44:1B:1D:0:8:E:1D:4:4:0:50:8:0:0:45:1B:1E:0:3:E:11:1:1:19:
```

I can't find 30:20 anywhere. What am I missing?

The baud rate is 115200 everywhere which I believe is the right one. The link is good because if I send char 'A' from PC over the serial connected to Mega, I get `41:` via ESP32 on the other side, which is correct.

Comment: Are both ESP32's serial ports implemented in hardware?  Do the research because if 1 is implemented in software the ESP32 may not be able to echo back everything it sees on the hardware serial port.

Comment: the bootloader responses on TX. and do you reset the board? the avrdude uses stk500 protocol, which is documented, no need to reverse engineer it

Comment: @st2000 According to online docs they are both hardware. It's also labeled on the board and when I send a random char from PC to Mega, I receive the correct value via ESP32, but when I look at what I receive during sketch upload, makes no sense. @Juraj I'm interested in what avrdude is sending first, which should be `0x30,0x20`,  not `0x1B,0x01`. I don't reset the board, the usb-to-serial chip already does it. The sketch upload from PC works. I just want to confirm the the first thing it sends is `0x30,0x20` to help me going.

Comment: Agreed, online it says the ESP32 has 3 hardware UARTs.  But when the Arduino development environment was ported to the ESP processor, did it actually use the hardware UARTs? And if it did, how well implemented is the firmware? For that matter, how well is the ESP's hardware implemented?  The type of problem I am concerned about occurs when many bytes are transferred rapidly. Of course the 1st byte, for such problems, should always make it through. Also, I agree with @Juraj. Use the existing documentation to develop you own programmer. Nothing says that what avrdude does is correct.

Comment: @Juraj In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\boards.txt` I have `mega.menu.cpu.atmega2560.upload.speed=115200`. I have also tried 57600 and 9600. What baud rate you think is being used?

Comment: The answer you link to is about the Uno. The Mega uses a different bootloader and, IIRC, a different protocol.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Yeah, I just noticed that if select `AVR ISP` programmer and click `Burn Bootloader` I can see `30:20` multiple times on the other side at the ESP32. So the serial it's fine. But there are no replies from the bootloader. I'll have to find an alternative for Mega. Thanks!

Comment: and what is what you try to do? AVR ISP is a programmer (hardware) to flash without bootloader

Comment: @Juraj The same protocol that AVR ISP is using, Uno and many others that have optiboot, are using. [Mega however is using wiring bootloader](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=640606.msg4335814#msg4335814), that is why I see `1B:1:0:1:E:1:14` as the first message, which is `wiring_open()`. In the end I want to be able to program mega via WiFi through internet. I think I'll try adapt ESP8266AVRISP for ESP32.

Comment: you can use my ArduinoOTA library to remote upload to Mega, if the Mega can access the network with some Arduino library (WiFiNINA?) https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA