# Arduino UNO stuck at 'uploading' with base sketch, nothing wired

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, avrdude

This question has been asked before and I have carefully read the other questions, but the solutions have not worked in my case, and the details are not the same as mine.

**Description**

The Arduino Uno is stuck at uploading with the error `avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00`, with the base sketch.

**Details**

- I am trying with the base empty sketch.
- Nothing is wired, nothing connected

**Important Remarks**

- A second Arduino UNO works perfectly fine with the same setup
- Loopback test worked - [Loopback test instructions](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360020366520-How-to-do-a-loopback-test)
- Cable and drivers work fine
- Correct port is selected
- Rebooting, resetting, upgrading the Arduino IDE have not solved the problem

**Important details**

- The TX LED is slightly but constantly on, and measuring the value of the TX Pin (Digital 1) outputs a value of 2.0 V. This also happens when feeding the Arduino with a 12 V supply, without USB. **EDIT** Got rid of this part by burning the bootloader via ISP with another Arduino - [Bootloader burn instructions](https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/4841602539164-Burn-the-bootloader-on-UNO-Mega-and-classic-Nano-using-another-Arduino)
- Checking the COM devices via powershell `mode` outputs something different between the two Arduinos: a locked value of `Baud: 115200` for the one not working, while for the one that works it displays `Baud: None`.

Answer (score 0):

> A second Arduino UNO works perfectly fine with the same setup

Sounds like your Uno is faulty. You could read my post here:

[Have I bricked my Arduino Uno? Problems with uploading to board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13292/have-i-bricked-my-arduino-uno-problems-with-uploading-to-board/13293#13293)

Also [What happens when code is uploaded using the bootloader?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15936/what-happens-when-code-is-uploaded-using-the-bootloader/15937#15937)

The Unos should be simply replaceable. That is, if your setup works on one, then unless you have done something weird to the other one (such as changing the fuses) then that should work too.

Is it a genuine one? Or a cheap knock-off? If it's cheap, well you got what you paid for. Get another.

I have [a post on my forum](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633) which lets you detect chip signatures and fuses (use your working Uno to run that). It may shed some light on what is happening.